# Selenium Maven Project

Tags: selenium

I am new to automated testing. I am trying to set up a Maven project for my Selenium test automation work. I put all the packages pertaining to envVariables, library, settings, resultLog, errScreenshots etc under src/test/java.

I have a couple of questions here

i)I showed this framework to my developer and he asked me to move some of the packages under src/test/resources. I am not sure whether this needs to be done or whatever I have configured is correct. If I need to move the packages to resources folder, what packages should I move? Can somebody please advise me on how to configure this?

ii) what should the src/main/java folder contain? I thought it will contain the src code of my application and test folder would contain unit tests and selenium tests. But my developer says the test folder will contain only unit test that test the classes in the src/main/java. It should not contain my selenium tests. Can somebody please explain this to me?

Regards
vasu

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the structure of your automation project. I prefer the following hierarchy in MAVEN projects

```
src
|-----main
|     |-----java
|           |-----Pages (contains application code arranged as one Class per Page)
|           |-----Steps (calls the page objects and methods called in Pages)
|-----test
      |------java
      |      |-----Test (Opens browser and calls steps to perform test - TestNG)
      |------resources
             |-----InputSheets
             |-----Environment Variables
```

The results are saved in C or D drive and are time stamped to avoid getting overwritten.

The automation helper library is created as a separate Maven project and is added as a dependency to the test project. In this way the helper library is independent from the test project and can be used across all projects if need arises.

All this being said, much of the structure is a matter of choice and varies according to your project requirements.

Answer (score 1):

"src/main/*" is for production code or test automation framework, not for test cases. "src/test/*" is for testing stuff, including selenium tests. "java" folders are for classes, "resource" folders are for configuration and test data.

I suggest creating a separate maven module for your testing stuff: test framework and test cases.

Please refer [maven directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) page for more information.

UPDATE: I have created [sample maven project](https://github.com/kpavlov/selenide-maven-sample) to show how run selenium test with [selenide](http://selenide.org).

Comment: Liked the effort you put and the links.